# Violinplot in R with discrete values

Tags: r, graphics, ggplot2, data-visualization, boxplot

I'm trying to create a violin plot in R from count data. The data I use is a number of mutations that is found in each sample for each source.

It looks something like this:

```
2 Source1
8 Source2
0 Source1
1 Source1
9 Source2
...
```

I already used the code below to create several plots.

```
ggplot(df_combined, aes(factor(names), y=mutations)) + 
geom_violin() +
geom_boxplot(width=.1, outlier.size=0, fill="grey50") +
stat_summary(fun.y=median, geom="point", fill="white", shape=21, size=4) +
xlab("Source") +
ylab("Number of mutations") +
theme(axis.text = element_text(colour = "black"))`
```

While most of them show up just fine, some of them start to 'wobble' (best way I can explain it) Here is an example that doesn't work.

[image: plot]

I guess this is because my data is discrete and not continuous but I can't find anything on how to change this for the violin plot. Is there any way I can get this to work with ggplot2 and geom_violin?

Data below:

```
structure(list(mutations = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), names = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L,   
1L), .Label = c("1kG", "CG"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("mutations", "names"), 
row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: could you give reproduce your data please? dput(head(df_combined)) e.g

Comment: I get this when I do that: structure(list(mutations = c(6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6), names = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("1kG", "CG"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("mutations", 
"names"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Comment: I think the "new" geom_dotplot implemented in ggplot2 would be another option. It's sort of like a violin plot, but with raw values (for example plot number nine: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_dotplot.html ).

Comment: This seems correct, if possibly aesthetically unpleasing (although I actually think it's kind of pretty): the wiggles are reflecting the bumps in density at the discrete values. What do you *want* the graph to look like? @RomanLuštrik's suggestion seems useful. Another potential solution would be to increase the bandwidth of the smoother used in geom_violin (i.e. smear out the density more over the values), although (1) I'm not sure geom_violin gives you that kind of control and (2) it might remove too much information from the plot ...

Comment: @BenBolker why not to put this as a solution?

Comment: Because it would take a little more work to make it into a real solution (e.g. I would want to give a `geom_dotplot` example).  In the meantime this has been cross-posted to the `ggplot2` google group, where Winston Chang has also provided an answer: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/JT653NWKilQ  While I'm at it, beanplots are another possible solution (although not within `ggplot2` as of now)

Answer (score 4):

I got the answer from Winston Chang [on the ggplot2 forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/ggplot2/JT653NWKilQ). The trick is to use `geom_violin(adjust=2)`, which will make the graph smooth.

Comment: For future reference, it's nice not to cross-post. Give one source a chance (say a day) to help you before turning to another, and mention the cross-posting as well.