# Make violin plot in r when you are already given the percent distribution

Tags: r, ggplot2

I was asked to make a violin plot that shows the distribution of ACT scores for students across four tiers of colleges (colleges are tiered based on quality measures.) The graph should have four violins, one for each quality tier (that is the x-axis). The y-axis will be ACT score. The wider the violin, the higher percent of students in that tier have that ACT score.

The data was presented to me already broken out by the percent of students in within each tier who have a certain ACT score. It is structured like so (this is not the real data, just a made-up sample):

```
structure(list(score = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), quality_tier = c("Tier 4", "Tier 4", 
"Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", 
"Tier 4", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", 
"Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1"), pct_students = c(0.25, 5, 10, 
15, 25, 15, 10, 12, 7, 0.75, 1.5, 6, 8, 12, 34, 17, 10, 6, 4, 
1.5, 5, 5, 13, 18, 5, 22, 13, 9, 5, 5, 0.8, 1, 14, 20, 25, 20, 
9, 8, 2, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I don't know how to turn this into a violin plot. All the tutorials online say use ggplot + geom_violin. But none of them include an example where you are actually given the percent distribution of a value, instead of calculating the percent distribution yourself. How should I restructure this data so that I can make a violin plot, or if I can't restructure the data, what data should I ask for?

Comment: Could you show what code you have tried; this will help understand your question better.

Comment: Were you given the numbers of students per Tier?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
```

#### Data

```
df <- structure(list(score = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 
3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), quality_tier = c("Tier 4", "Tier 4", 
"Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", "Tier 4", 
"Tier 4", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", 
"Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 3", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", "Tier 2", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1", 
"Tier 1", "Tier 1", "Tier 1"), pct_students = c(0.25, 5, 10, 
15, 25, 15, 10, 12, 7, 0.75, 1.5, 6, 8, 12, 34, 17, 10, 6, 4, 
1.5, 5, 5, 13, 18, 5, 22, 13, 9, 5, 5, 0.8, 1, 14, 20, 25, 20, 
9, 8, 2, 0.2)), row.names = c(NA, -40L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

#### data wrangle

`geom_violin` wants to have the count data rather than the processed percentage data. Not knowing the number of people in each tier I've arbitrarily multiplied the percentage values by 10 to get whole numbers.

`tidyr::uncount` does just that, so then you can carryout a simple `ggplot` visualisation.

```
df1 <- 
  df %>% 
  mutate(nr = pct_students*10) %>% 
  uncount(nr)
```

#### plot

```
  
ggplot(df1, aes(quality_tier, score))+
  geom_violin()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Give yourself more credit Peter (it's why I asked him how many students).  Has to be about 10 to give you the percentages shown in the original table.  It's also the number of score categories per quality tier so it's far better than arbitrary

Comment: Thanks @ChuckP; but I don't think it really matters whether you assume there are 10 or 10,000 students, the plots would look the same. I reckon it would work if you used the percentage values. The important bit was  to `uncount` the data. I was going to see if geom_violin had a `stat = "identity"` option so it could be treated like `geom_hist`. That's for another day.

Comment: LOL @Peter that's what I was working on before I saw your answer but spoiler alert try `pct_students*100` in your code and the plots will look different, go 1000 and they'll look very different.

Comment: Hmm @ChuckP I think some homework is in order to better understand what is being plotted. I think the issue is that in effect it is discrete data which is being plotted rather than continuous data.Quick look up in the documentation: "A violin plot is a compact display of a continuous distribution." So geom_violin may not be the right visualisation for this data! Hmm, need to ponder on this...

Comment: @ChuckP This link provides a useful introduction to the issue of plotting discrete data with `geom_violin`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13744979/violinplot-in-r-with-discrete-values. `geom_violin` includes an `adjust` argument which allows "smoothing" of the bumps.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very oldfashioned approach: simply build your violin from scratch if you can't use ggplot's stat to parameterise a violin for you. Assuming the `dat` variable is your example data.

```
# Split by group
mylist <- split(dat, dat$quality_tier)

# Parameterise as polygons
newdat <- lapply(seq_along(mylist), function(i) {
  dat <- mylist[[i]]
  new <- data.frame(
    x = c(dat$pct_students, -rev(dat$pct_students)),
    y = c(dat$score, rev(dat$score)),
    i = i
  )
  new
})

# Reconstruct
newdat <- do.call(rbind, newdat)
newdat$group <- names(mylist)[newdat$i]

# Set widths of violins
violin_width <- 0.9
newdat$x <- scales::rescale(newdat$x, to = c(-1, 1) * 0.5 * violin_width)

# Plot polygons
ggplot(newdat, aes(x + i, y, fill = group)) +
  geom_polygon() +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = unique(newdat$i),
                     labels = unique(newdat$group))
```

[image]

I know it doesn't look awesome, but if your collaborator wants better plots, he should give better data.

Comment: I like this approach because it's most faithful to the given data. I guess you could use splines to smooth out the polygons if you really wanted that look. I also wonder if ribbons would be easier than polygons?

Answer (score 0):

Another dplyr solution, using `sample`

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  split(df$quality_tier) %>%
  lapply(function(x) {
    tibble(tier = rep(x$quality_tier[1], 1000), 
           score = sample(x$score, 1000, prob = x$pct_students, replace = TRUE))
    }) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  ggplot(aes(tier, score, fill = tier)) + 
  geom_violin() +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>